# PHP 500 Internal Server Error- mail function

Tags: php, html, function, syntax-error

I'm getting the 500 Internal Server Error. I called goDaddy and they told me it's not something on their end. I also don't have a .htaccess file. I checked the contact page and checked spelling it is calling the right .php file.

This code was working perfectly. I tried to change something it didn't work. I tried going back to the original code and now that doesn't work either. I don't have a backup. I commented out line by line to pin-point the problem if I erase the `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` part I don't get an error but obviously don't receive anything. Here is the website if that helps to inspect.

http://www.crownjewelre.com/contacts.html

```
  <?php

$first_name    = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name    = $_POST['last_name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$telephone    = $_POST['telephone'];
$comments    = $_POST['comments'];


// multiple recipients
$to  = 'michaelgaraysi@yahoo.com' . ', '; // note the comma


// subject
$subject.= "CrownJewelRe question From: ".$first_name." ".$last_name. "\n";

// message
$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact Information</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name:  </td><th>".$first_name."</th><th>".$last_name."</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:  </td><th>".$email."</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Telephone:  </td><th>".$telephone."</th>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <br><br>
       <p>Comments: &nbsp;  <strong>".$comments."</strong></th>



</body>
</html>
";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: This probably won't fix anything but try using `$subject =` instead of `$subject.=`

Comment: Also, try removing the random comma in `$to`. Why is it in there and why is it commented to notice it?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but none of those helped :/

Comment: I think MonkeyZeus is right. You are expanding an non-existent variable.

Comment: Try removing the names in the headers, and see if it works.
If it works, add them again but put quotes around them if they contain spaces, like Birthday Reminder

Comment: I tried commenting out the whole $to and it didn't help. I took out the comma already . Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
$to  = 'michaelgaraysi@yahoo.com' . ', ';
```

to

```
$to  = 'michaelgaraysi@yahoo.com';
```

and

```
$subject.= "CrownJewelRe question From: ".$first_name." ".$last_name. "\n";
```

to

```
$subject= "CrownJewelRe question From: ".$first_name." ".$last_name. "\n";
```

and finally, try to run this simple php mailer script, and then apply your changes,

```
<?php
$to      = 'michaelgaraysi@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: birthday@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: birthday@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

?>

Comment: I did that, but still didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

like the others $subject.= is auto-expand of a non existing var but that not the problem here :)

1st : have you tested a blank page with only the function mail :

```
mail ('michaelgaraysi@yahoo.com','test','message corpus');
```

if its working its not a missconfig of youre PHP.

2nd : How can you use in 2015 the mail function, its have a high spam rate, instead use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer or other.

I think it will solve your problem  or maybe you just need to remove the "\n"; on $subject :)